# Как правильно реализовывать корзину Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cart

Всем привет! Я новичок, поэтому хотелось бы услышать несколько советов.

Делаю тестовый инет магазин, очередь дошла до корзины. В учебных роликах показывали как ее реализовывать, путем добавления выбранных товаров в БД, но это вероятно не совсем правильно, в комментах пишут что лучше делать через сессии, кто то писал что можно через AJAX запросы. Только я не совсем понял, они вместе реализуются либо один из двух вариантов?

Так в итоге какой вариант самый оптимальный? Можете посоветовать, что почитать или где подсмотреть реализацию на Laravel?

Спасибо!

Comment: аякс запросы не имеют отношения к хранению корзины. делать можно и на БД, и на сессиях. для тестового сервера делай как угодно, хоть в базе хоть в сессиях. если ты пишешь нормальный код, то потом поменять будет несложно. А если обычное спагетти, то тем более без разницы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации корзины можно использовать разные механизмы, у каждого свои минусы:

1. Данные о товарах из корзины хранятся в БД, должны быть подвязаны к конкретному пользователю. Этот способ хранения не подходит, если на вашем сайте нет механизма Аутентификации.
2. Данные о товарах храняться в Сессиях. Минус данного способа - время нахождение товаров в корзине, которе определяется временем жизни php сессии.
3. Данные о товарах из корзины хранятся в локальном кэше браузера. Из минусов - пользователь может случайно очистить кжш и потерять данные с корзины.

По моему мнению, лучше всего использовать комбинацию из вышеуказанных решений, например, если пользователь не авторизован на сайте - хранить данные в кэше или сессии, а когда пользователь авторизуется - переносить данные из сессии в БД и начинать хранить новые добавленные продукты там.